# 2D dynamic array of structures does not work as intended

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

So, I have a 2D array of structures. I enter the structure element by element, yet the program prints some random data, instead of the entered information. For example, `ptr[0][0].Flat_ID` should be 101, yet it prints  `8` and as for the other elements, it's total gibberish. Any ideas why it does that?
Structure:

```
typedef struct
{
   int Flat_ID;
   int count_Rooms;
   int count_Adults;
   int count_Children;
   char Family_Surname[20];
   char Date[15];
   float rent;
}S_Apartament;
```

And the program inside `main()`:

```
int floors=1, flats_per_floor=2;
S_Apartament Flats;
S_Apartament **ptr = (S_Apartament **)malloc(sizeof(S_Apartament*) * floors);//Declaring an array of pointers. It has to be dynamic, as per the assignment
        if(ptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory fail");
            free(ptr);
            exit(8);

        }
        for (int i = 0; i <  floors; i++)
        {
            ptr[i] = (S_Apartament *)malloc(sizeof(S_Apartament)*flats_per_floor);//Each pointer from the first array now is an array of its own, with elements being structures
            if(ptr[i] == NULL)
            {
                printf("Memory fail");
                free(ptr);
                exit(8);

            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <  floors; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < flats_per_floor; j++)
            {
                printf("ID:\n");
                scanf("%d", &ptr[i][j].Flat_ID);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Rooms:\n");
                scanf("%d", &ptr[i][j].count_Rooms);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Adults:\n");
                scanf("%d", &ptr[i][j].count_Adults);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Children:\n");
                scanf("%d", &ptr[i][j].count_Children);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Name:\n");
                scanf("%s", ptr[i][j].Family_Surname);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Date of entry: \n");
                scanf("%s", ptr[i][j].Date);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Rent:\n");
                scanf("%f", &ptr[i][j].rent);
                printf("\n");
                ptr[i][j]=Flats;
            }
        }
for(int i=0; i< floors; i++)//Prints read information
        {
            for(int j=0; j< flats_per_floor; j++)
            {
                printf("ID: %d\n", ptr[i][j].Flat_ID);
                printf("Rooms: %d\n", ptr[i][j].count_Rooms);
                printf("Adults: %d\n", ptr[i][j].count_Adults);
                printf("Children: %d\n", ptr[i][j].count_Children);
                printf("Name: %s\n", ptr[i][j].Family_Surname);
                printf("Date of entry: %s\n", ptr[i][j].Date);
                printf("Rent: %0.2f\n", ptr[i][j].rent);

            }
            printf("-----------------");
            printf("\n");
        }
free(ptr);
```

Here is a sample output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pWyg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `ptr[i][j]=Flats;` is to be removed at the start of each iteration, because the program does not save the information at the correct location.
The loop should look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <  floors; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < flats_per_floor; j++)
            {
                printf("ID:\n");
                scanf("%d", &ptr[i][j].Flat_ID);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Rooms:\n");
                scanf("%d", &ptr[i][j].count_Rooms);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Adults:\n");
                scanf("%d", &ptr[i][j].count_Adults);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Children:\n");
                scanf("%d", &ptr[i][j].count_Children);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Name:\n");
                scanf("%s", ptr[i][j].Family_Surname);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Date of entry: \n");
                scanf("%s", ptr[i][j].Date);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Rent:\n");
                scanf("%f", &ptr[i][j].rent);
                printf("\n");

            }
        }
```

Comment: Better: "The command `ptr[i][j]=Flats;` does not make sense because `Flats`'s value is indeterminate.  It should simply be removed."

Answer (score 0):

You do not check the result of `scanf`. It was just unsuccessful and the member was not assigned the value.